# How to prevent LiveData observers from being activated when Fragment is not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, fragment-lifecycle

I want to use `LiveData` in a `Fragment` to observe the change of some data. Now let's suppose:

1. Both the `Fragment A` and `Fragment B` have their own containers layout in `Activity`, which means we will call `FragmentTransaction#add()` separately for them and their `onPause()` or `onResume()` will not be called during adding(UI change) because of no `FragmentTransaction#replace()` action.
2. B's container is larger than A's, which means if B is added, users cannot see A.
3. In A there is a `LiveData` observer named as O, it will observe the change of some data, and update UI according to it. The key is: **we want to play some animation for the change, instead of just calling properties setter (like `TextView#setText()`) naively**. For example, maybe the animation is the one played after we called `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted()`

After adding B, A is considered as invisible to users. However, both the lifecycle of `Fragment A` or of its `View` by calling `getViewLifecycleOwner()` is still on `STARTED` and `RESUMED` state. As a result, the animation will play after the data changes observed by O but users cannot see it from the beginning.

How can we solve this problem? Any ideas or answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding B (which consumes the space supposedly alloted for A), it is better to also remove fragment A. You get multiple benefits for this:

1) You solve your problem. (Thats if youre using `viewLifeCycleOwner` in observing your `LiveData`)
2) You decrease memory consumption of your app, since the Fragment A's view will be torn down.

This is

> which means we will call FragmentTransaction#add() separately

is also not a problem. Note that you can chain `FragmentTransaction`s such as:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(view1.id, fragmentB)
    .remove(fragmentA)
    .commit()
```

Comment: Note that `hide()` literally just sets the alpha on the Fragment. It has no effect on the Lifecycle of the Fragment.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction#show()/hide()` will not influence the lifecycle of either `Fragment` or its view

Comment: @ianhanniballake ohh... then just use `.remove()` then i guess?

Comment: by the way hi @ianhanniballake!! :D :D

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones We cannot use `FragmentTransaction#remove()` in this case, because A should not be removed just for this reason and it has many other things to do.

Comment: @ywwynm how about `.detach()` then?

Comment: Also, it seems that the `it has many other things to do` isn't view related so I don't think you need fragment for that (unless im wrong). Have you considered moving that `it has many other things to do` to a `ViewModel` perhaps or to the `Activity` itself or where ever you want to place it.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones You're still talking about removing A but I don't want to do that. By saying "many other things", they are still possibly UI-related because not all UI change should be with animation. I just don't want the lifecycle of A remaining `STARTED` or `RESUMED` in that situation and this is all about lifecycle, not the fragment itself.

Comment: The arguement remains. You can seperate that logic outside of the fragment scope. Then youre not restricted about your fragment removal, etc. You cannot change the fact that LiveData always listens to change as long as the observer is active but you can control how you structure your code.